# How to resolve duplicate key <PACKAGE NAME> issue of Pkg?

Tags: julia, package-management

Objective: To get installed package particulars using status command of Pkg module

Procedure:

```
$ julia
julia> ]
(v1.1) pkg> status
```

Output:

```
ERROR: Pkg.TOML.ParserError(258, 263, "duplicate key `Dates`")
Stacktrace:
 [1] parse(::IOStream) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/ext/TOML/src/TOML.jl:33
 [2] #open#310(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::typeof(Pkg.TOML.parse), ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./iostream.jl:369
 [3] open at ./iostream.jl:367 [inlined]
 [4] parsefile(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/ext/TOML/src/TOML.jl:46
 [5] load_stdlib() at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/Types.jl:338
 [6] Pkg.Types.Context() at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/Types.jl:347
 [7] Context!(::Array{Pair{Symbol,Any},1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/Types.jl:368
 [8] Context! at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:526 [inlined]
 [9] do_status!(::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:603
 [10] #invokelatest#1(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./essentials.jl:742
 [11] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./essentials.jl:741
 [12] do_cmd!(::Pkg.REPLMode.PkgCommand, ::REPL.LineEditREPL) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:561
 [13] #do_cmd#30(::Bool, ::Function, ::REPL.LineEditREPL, ::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:536
 [14] do_cmd at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:532 [inlined]
 [15] (::getfield(Pkg.REPLMode, Symbol("##48#51")){REPL.LineEditREPL,REPL.LineEdit.Prompt})(::REPL.LineEdit.MIState, ::Base.GenericIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Bool) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/REPLMode.jl:967
 [16] #invokelatest#1 at ./essentials.jl:742 [inlined]
 [17] invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:741 [inlined]
 [18] run_interface(::REPL.Terminals.TextTerminal, ::REPL.LineEdit.ModalInterface, ::REPL.LineEdit.MIState) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/REPL/src/LineEdit.jl:2273
 [19] run_frontend(::REPL.LineEditREPL, ::REPL.REPLBackendRef) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/REPL/src/REPL.jl:1035
 [20] run_repl(::REPL.AbstractREPL, ::Any) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/REPL/src/REPL.jl:192
 [21] (::getfield(Base, Symbol("##734#736")){Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool})(::Module) at ./client.jl:362
 [22] #invokelatest#1 at ./essentials.jl:742 [inlined]
 [23] invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:741 [inlined]
 [24] run_main_repl(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./client.jl:346
 [25] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:284
 [26] _start() at ./client.jl:436
```

Observation:
Dates and its dependent packages have only one uuid as follows:
Contents of `"/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Dates/Project.toml"`

```
name = "Dates"
uuid = "ade2ca70-3891-5945-98fb-dc099432e06a"
...
```

and for its dependent packages:
Content of `"/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/<PACKAGE_NAME>/Project.toml"`

```
...
[deps]
...
Dates = "ade2ca70-3891-5945-98fb-dc099432e06a"
...
```

Please help me in resolving the duplicate key issue of Pkg!

Comment: Have you manually messed with files in the Julia stdlib?

Comment: I am not sure! But, packages are installed in stdlib folder.